# Square and triangles in a simple geometry problem

Tags: geometry

Given $ABCD$ is a square with side "$a$"  and  both $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle BCF$ are equilateral triangles, how can I find the area of $\triangle BEF$ ?

I know that $BE=BF=a$ ... but I would need $EF$ for the perimeter formula for the area .

The situation is represented here :

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Equilateral triangle" means all three sides are equal. Did you mean that, or "isosceles triangle" (two equal sides)?

Comment: Ah, or did you mean $ABE$ and $BCF$ are equilateral?

Comment: Exactly, thanks, i just fixed.

Comment: One might as well do crude, and calculate. Introduce coordinates. You can choos $a$ to be anything convenient, and scale later.

Comment: It's some elementary highschool problem my gf has and i as simple as it sounds, i cant figure it out.Must have some simple solution.

Comment: $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)^2 = 2.$$

Comment: Okay, figured out one solution. just have to draw a rectangular triangle with hypotenuse EF, and we know its cathetus.Then we just use perimeter formula for BEF. I wonder if theres simpler way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\angle EBF=90^\circ\implies \;\Delta BEF\;\;\text{is an isosceles straight-angle triangle}\implies$$

$$EF=\frac2{\sqrt2}a=\sqrt2\,a$$

Comment: Lol, yes, so obvious that angle was 90. Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Incidentally, if the angle had been other than $90^\circ$ then you could still get the area without calculating the other side length: $A = \frac{1}{2}bc\sin\theta$, where $b$, $c$ are the sides and $\theta$ is the included angle.

Comment: @Théophile, perhaps. Yet the problem was said to be at *elementary* high school geometry so trigonometry either isn't welcome or else it is a last resource...

Comment: @DonAntonio Sure. I was thinking of a situation where the angle was still simple ($30^\circ$, etc.), and the point is to avoid introducing a system of coördinates (which to me is more of a last resource).

Comment: @DonAntonio, why do we need to find $EF$?

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it easier to divide the area of the square $BEDF$ in two?
[image]